# XLconnect cell style not preserverd R

Tags: r, xlconnect

I'm using the 'XLconnect' package in R to write data to a .xlsx file. I use this package because I have predefined style in my workbook which I want to preserve. I used this before in other projects where it worked fine, but now it doesn't seem to work. My predefined workbook looks like this;

[image]

The code I use (as example) is as follows;

```
library(stringr)
library(XLConnect)
library(rJava)

test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
wb <- loadWorkbook("COS_OVERVIEW.xlsx", create = TRUE)
setStyleAction(wb, XLC$STYLE_ACTION.NONE)
writeWorksheet(wb, test, "Overview", startRow = 2, startCol = 1, header = F)
saveWorkbook(wb)
xlcFreeMemory()
gc()
```

But the the output looks like this;

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XLConnect/versions/1.0.7/topics/setStyleAction-methods), `XLC$STYLE_ACTION.PREDEFINED` might do the trick.

Comment: @I_O I tried this and other styles but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately, same output